# React Native app, installing release apk, parse error

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[meizu m2 mini android 5.1 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyATf.jpg)

I have parse error on some devices, but i cannot find reason, because for example it works on one Meizu and not working on another Meizu, and the same with android version, it work on Android 5 on one phone and not working on another phone with android 5. It not works if i build app release apk and try to install it manually, but if i try to debug with usb cabel - it works , also it works if i install app by using command `react-native run-android --variant=release`

Answer (score 1):

This is due to already installed debuged mode app in your device. Uninstall previously installed debug apk from your devive  then install new released apk.

Comment: Did not help  (it is also happened when i installing it first time on phone)

Comment: Try to install the released apk from android/app/build/outputs/apk

Comment: Did you all steps given in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

Comment: try by  enabling "def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true" property in "android/app/build.gradle",.